# Selenium Webdriver Python page object MainPageLocators class why does it use an asterisk infront of the class name

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been following the page object model for my Selenium Webdriver tests in Python.  I have followed the sample from GitHub.
URL is: https://github.com/baijum/selenium-python/blob/master/source/page-objects.rst

When you call the locator from the MainPageLocators class e.g from the URL.

```
element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
```

It uses an asterisk in front of the class name *MainPageLocators.
Why does it use * ?

It does not work if you use MainPageLocators, you have to use *MainPageLocators.

This is no good because when i use the WebDriverWait it does not work with *MainPageLocators or MainPageLocators.
E.g.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((*MainPageLocators.locator)))
```

I have to to do it this way for it to work which defeats the purpose of having the locators in one place.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'button_id')))
```

Why the asterisk in front of MainPageLocators?
Why does *MainPageLocators not work inside the WebDriverWait?
It does work if you do

self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.locator)

But it does not work if you use it in the WebDriverWait

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `*` is the [argument-unpacking operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/#calling-a-function). It tells Python to unpack the values in the sequence that follows and pass them as arguments to the function. For example,

```
foo(*(1, 2, 3))
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
```

---

Since `MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON` is defined like this:

```
class MainPageLocators(object):
    """A class for main page locators. All main page locators should come here"""
    GO_BUTTON = (By.ID, 'submit')
```

it follows that `find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)` is equivalent to

```
find_element(By.ID, 'submit')
```

This works since `find_element` [expects 2 arguments](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements).

---

In contrast, `EC.element_to_be_clickable` [expects a single 2-tuple as its argument](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits). Therefore you would not want to use the argument-unpacking operator here. Instead, just pass the 2-tuple directly:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'submit'))
```

or use

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
```

Comment: That's really great.  I understand this now.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This is great to know. Thank you @unutbu